# Verificar aba fechada

Tags: javascript

Eu achei na internet o seguinte código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var popup = null;

function Abrir() {
    if (popup!=null && popup.closed)
    alert("A Janela foi fechada.n Abrindo novamente.");

    if (popup!=null && !popup.closed){
    }
    else {
        popup = window.open("http://www.google.com","Jan","height=350,width=200");popup.focus();
    }
    setTimeout("Abrir()", 2000); //javascript trabalha com milesimos
}
</script>
```

Ele se encaixa bem no sistema que eu quero fazer, o qual verifica se a aba aberta ainda está aberta, porém necessita de um ajuste que eu não sei fazer.

Esse código está em *loop*, quando ele dá a mensagem que a janela foi fechada, ele abre ela novamente. Teria como ele somente mandar a mensagem? E mandar só uma vez não ficar mandando toda hora? Ou seja, fazer com que o *timer* rode somente até ele detectar que a janela foi fechada, assim ele emite o alerta e para de executar a função novamente.

**Atualização**: Consegui montar o seguinte código, o que acham?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var popup = null;

function Abrir() {
    popup = window.open("http://www.google.com","Jan","height=800,width=600");popup.focus();
    setTimeout("Verifica()", 2000);
}
function Verifica() {
    if (popup!=null && popup.closed){
    $("#aguardetop").hide("slow");
    $("#sucessotop").fadeIn();
    Adiciona();
    return;
    }
    if (popup!=null && !popup.closed){
    }
    setTimeout("Verifica()", 2000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Você quer usar o `setTimeout` mesmo? ele vai executar o código uma vez somente após 2 *segs*, será que não é o `setInterval` que você quer usar?

Comment: o `SetTimeout` no caso é para executar a verificação até o momento em que o usuário fechar o popup, já que eu não consegui trabalhar com o `onbeforeunload`

Comment: Na verdade eu não vi muita diferença rsrs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a [função `setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) para estar verificando se o *popup* ainda está aberto, quando ele for fechado, você cancela a ação com a [função `clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval).

```js
function aoFecharJanela(){
  alert("A janela foi fechada pelo usuário");
}
function abrirPopup(url, windowName, opts, callback) {
    var popup = window.open(url, windowName, opts);
    var intervalo = setInterval(function() {
        try {
            if (popup == null || popup.closed) {
                window.clearInterval(intervalo);
                callback(popup);
            }
        }
        catch (e) { }
    }, 2000);
    return popup;
}

abrirPopup("http://www.google.com","Jan","height=350,width=200", aoFecharJanela);
```

[**`Exemplo`**](http://output.jsbin.com/hepazagave/1)

Comment: mas estea função `setInterval` não estaria fazendo praticamente a mesma coisa do que a `setTimer` só que de uma maneira diferente?

Comment: @Guilherme Sim. Mas tem um porém, o [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) vai executar o código a cada *2 segs* num *loop* até que você cancele com o [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval), já o [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) vai executar o código **uma vez** somente após os *2 segs*.

Comment: @Guilherme Deu certo usando desta forma?

Comment: Na verdade o setTimeout não vai executar somente uma vez, ele vai entrar em loop também! Pois passados dois segundos ele vai chamar a função `Verifica()`, e se caso o popup esteja aberto (`if (popup!=null && !popup.closed)`) ele vai executar a verifica novamente, até que o popup esteja fechado. Por isso não entendi a diferença entre as duas.

Comment: @Guilherme Você está certo, eu não tinha reparado no teu *2º* código, lá você chama *duas* vezes o `setTimeout´ e verifica o status da variável `popup` duas vezes também. Percebeu alguma diferença entre o teu *2º* código e este da resposta?

Comment: para te falar a verdade eu nem testei o seu ja que vi que faz a mesma coisa hehe. Mas vou introduzir ele no código e ver como se comporta. Se for igual marco como a resposta para a pergunta :) Caso contrário eu informo o problema aqui rsrs

Comment: @Guilherme Conseguiu testar o código?

Comment: Opa, tinha esquecido de atualziar rsrs desculpe! Testei sim e faz a mesma função que o meu :) Marcado como melhor resposta muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

**Seu script está ok!**

**onbeforeunload** vai ser somente disparado no momento em que a janela aberta estiver prestes a carregar a página interna. Se neste momento você clicar no botão de fechar, o **alert** vai ser acionado normalmente.

***Chrome*** e ***Firefox*** tem esse comportamento.
***IE***, nega ação e nada acontece.

Comment: Não entendi. A moral não seria ele (script) executar o alerta assim que a página fecha?

Comment: Caro Guilherme, o comando onbeforeunload executa uma ação quando um documento está prestes a ser descarregado.

Comment: E tu sabe como fazer para ele executar o comando ao fechar a página?

Comment: Infelizmente não conheço uma função javascript para seu propósito.